# OpenGL - Uniform not being passed properly?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I've got an extremely simple fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

// Interpolated values from the vertex shaders
in vec3 positionW;

// Output data
out vec3 frag_color;

uniform vec3 alsoLightW;

void main(void) {
    vec3 temp = normalize(alsoLightW);
    frag_color = vec3((temp.x + 1.0) / 2, (temp.y + 1.0) / 2, (temp.z + 1.0) / 2);
}
```

All it does is normalize a uniform vec3 I've passed to it, and then set my fragment color to it (between 0 and 1 - so a 0 vector would have a color of 0.5, 0.5, 0.5). I print this vector out in my c++ code, and verify that it is passed in properly with renderdoc, however the actual colors that it spits out are consistently wrong - they don't seem to have anything to do with my uniform, but it's always giving me the same color, regardless. For instance, my vec3 is supposed to have a y-coordinate of 0 so I expect a Green value of 0.5, but according to renderdoc, I'm instead getting something around .2

What could be the reason for this? It's been driving me crazy, and is making my much more complicated shader not work at all.

Edit: passing uniform to OpenGL:

```
ctx.shader->Enable();

...

glm::vec3 oppOffset = *Object::globalOffset;
oppOffset *= -1;

glUniform3fv(lightLocation, 1, glm::value_ptr(oppOffset));

glm::vec3 norm = glm::normalize(oppOffset);
//Prints the correct information
std::cout << (norm.x + 1) / 2 << "," << (norm.y + 1) / 2 << "," << (norm.z + 1) / 2 << std::endl;
```

Edit2: I tried passing them as individual floats, and I'm getting the same exact weird numbers as before. [I've uploaded an image of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VIe0.png) - the bottom left numbers are the ones I'm getting from cout, and the top right are the ones that RenderDoc are giving me

This is what my uniform passing looks like now:

```
glm::vec3 norm = glm::normalize(oppOffset);
norm = (norm + glm::vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)) * glm::vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
float x, y, z;
x = norm.x;
y = norm.y;
z = norm.z;
ctx.shader->uniform1fv("lightx", 1, &x);
ctx.shader->uniform1fv("lighty", 1, &y);
ctx.shader->uniform1fv("lightz", 1, &z);
std::cout << x << "," << y << "," << z << std::endl;
```

And my shader:

```
#version 330 core

// Interpolated values from the vertex shaders
in vec3 positionW;

// Output data
out vec3 frag_color;

uniform float lightx;
uniform float lighty;
uniform float lightz;

void main(void) {
    //vec3 temp = normalize(alsoLightW);
    frag_color = vec3(lightx, lighty, lightz);
}
```

Something very weird is happening...

Comment: Can You post the code that actually passes the value of `alsoLightW` to the shader?

Comment: I updated the post with the information

Comment: And how is `lightLocation` obtained? Is the shader bound at when it happens?

Comment: It's also worth saying that I can pass this same vector to a *different* fragment shader in a different rendering phase, and it works just fine. I don't change the vector at all in between.

Comment: I use `ctx.shader->getUniformLocation("alsoLightW")`, which is just a wrapper for glGetUniformLocation

Comment: I figure that I know I've got the location correct, as the alsoLightW changes in a way that is similar to how I expect it would change, but the numbers themselves aren't expected.

Comment: Do you get the expected number when you output a constant color, let's say `frag_color = vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);`?

Comment: Yes. I'm starting to think it might be a conversion issue with whatever type glm uses in its vec3s and GL_FLOAT because I tried passing them individually instead of as a vector, and it gave me the exact same result.

Comment: I added another update to my post with an image of what I've been talking about.

Comment: If the half-cut line above the marked one shows the format of the buffer, then that's the problem. You have an SRGB buffer. Your output get's gamma corrected before it is written to the output. Edit: Yes, this is the problem. Your output values are the `pow(temp, 2.2)`;

Comment: Hoooooly shit there's no way I would have been able to figure that out. Please submit an answer so I can mark it correct.

Comment: Done. Unluckily I can't tell you how to change it (because we don'T know how you are creating the render-buffer). Feel free to submit a new question if you need details on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with the uniform (or passing the uniform) but with the format of the renderbuffer. The buffer has a SRGB format meaning that it will not store linear colors but gamma corrected ones.

All your results will be determined by this equation:

`color_srgb = pow(color_rgb, 2.2);`